# guide to create debian package in netbeans

Tags: c++, ubuntu, debian, packaging, netbeans-7.3

I've written a C++ application aided by netbeans on ubuntu. In netbeans there is a build feature to build debian package. When I build the package using it I am not getting desired result. The files I am installing to linux filesystem using makefile are not being put into debian package.

in my makefile

```
install:
    install config.xml /etc/${APPNAME}.conf.xml
    install devices.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/${APPNAME}.rules
    install error.log /var/log/${APPNAME}.log
    install init.conf /etc/init/${APPNAME}.conf
    install init.d /etc/init.d/${APPNAME}
    chmod u+x ${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}
    ./${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}} -i
```

but after building the package with netbeans, in the build .deb archive there is only usr/bin/${APPNAME} file. How to build debian package as expected.

Comment: Have you checked the packaging guide at http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/ ? The basic layout of the debian directory in your package is described there. For your question, it would help to attach debian/rules to your question.

Comment: @TeTeT I followed http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

Comment: can't netbeans take me through steps and confugurations needed to build the package

Comment: @neckTwi Can you check in Project Properties > Build > Packaging section Packaging Files? Normally you need to add them there too.

Comment: @jmolinaso are the variables of Makefile;${APPNAME}; are accessible in the configuration window? And also I couldn't find provision to set copyright file and changelog

Comment: Can't say it yet, I'm also busy getting my head around the packaging system for debian :) I marked that one as a follow up too. If I get somewhere I'll share it here too